# $P(A_n)\sim e^{-n}$, then there is a $c>1$ such that $P(A_n)\leq c^{-n}$ for al $n$?

Tags: probability

Let $P(A_n)\sim e^{-n}$,

Then, does there exist a $c>1$ such that $P(A_n)\leq c^{-n}$ for all $n$?

---

I am not sure, but I think "for all n" is not correct.

Let $c>1$ and choose $d\geq c$. Then
$$
P(A_n)\sim d^{-n} 
$$
and $P(A_n)\leq c^{-n}$,

but only for **almost all** $n$, or?

Comment: Assume that$P(A_n)\sim e^{-n}$. Then there exists some $c>1$ such that $P(A_n)\leqslant c^{-n}$ for every $n$ **if and only if** $P(A_n)\ne1$ for every $n$.

Comment: But if I have $P(B_n)\leqslant  P(A_n)\sim e^{-n}$, then I have that $P(B_n)\leqslant c^{-n}$ for **all** n, since $e^{-n}\sim c^{-n}$ for $c>1$, right?

Comment: No, not right, again because of the problem of the first values, about which the equivalent says nothing.

Comment: But isn't the original statement true for almost all n? Since $P(A_n)\sim e^{-n}$ implies that $P(A_n)\neq 1$ for almost all $n$, or?

Comment: For every $n$ large enough, yes.

Answer (score 0):

$P\left(A_{n}\right)\sim e^{-n}$ (probably) stands for $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{n}P\left(A_{n}\right)=1$$
If that is the case and $0<c<e$ then $c^{n}P\left(A_{n}\right)=\left(\frac{c}{e}\right)^{n}e^{n}P\left(A_{n}\right)\rightarrow0$. Showing that $P(A_n)\leq c^{-n}$ for $n$ large enough. Note that $e:=\exp1>1$ so we can find a $c>1$ that satisfies this condition.

---

If indeed $P(A_n)\leq c^{-n}$ for *each* $n$ for some $c>1$ then $P(A_n)<1$ for *each* $n$.

This however is not a consequence of $P(A_n)\sim e^{-n}$. For instance take $P(A_n)=1$ for $n\leq N$ and $P(A_n)=e^{-n}$ for $n>N$ where $N$ denotes some positive integer. Then $P\left(A_{n}\right)\sim e^{-n}$ .

Comment: What do you mean by $0<c<e$? What is $e$?

Comment: The same $e$ that you are using in your question. $e=\exp1\sim2.7>1$ I expect.

Comment: $e^{-n}$ means $\exp(-n)$.

Comment: I know that. But what are you trying to say by that? If $e:=\exp(1)$ then $\exp(n)=e^n$ (and $\exp(-n)=e^{-n}$).